# How do I prove that this force equation is wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

Ok this is a simple setup. Pulley is massless and frictionless. String is massless. Pulley is fixed to a wall. The question asks me to find out the acceleration of the two blocks and the tension force acting at the point $D$.

$m_{2}$ $>$ $m_{1}$

The left image is how I did it, which is supposed to be the right way.

The right image is how my friend did it. According to him, if we consider the two blocks, string and pulley together, gravity on two blocks and the tension force at $D$ are the external forces. So they must equal. I know that his reasoning is wrong. Yet I can't seem to prove it how.

Comment: Why is it being voted to be closed? I have made a genuine attempt at proving it wrong. But I hit a roadblock, which is why I asked here. It is not a question that needs to be solved. I am looking for hints on how to go about proving it wrong. I tried, really tired but I have no clue as to what's wrong in the equation on the right

Comment: Your friend is assuming that the sum of external forces on the system is zero, but it's not: the center of mass moves.